# List of X keysims

Tags: x11, xorg, x-dwm

I was adding keybindings to dwm, but I when I wanted to add keybindings for "<" and ">" I couldn't find any lists online that included their notations (like `XK_bracketleft`).

Could anyone tell me the their codes of point me towards a list that includes them?

Comment: ??? These are called "less" and "greater" signs, tke keysyms are XK_less and XK_greater.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You sound surprised that anyone would not know that. Perhaps you work with them so much you're suffering from this problem: https://xkcd.com/2501/

Comment: @IMSoP Suffering? Nah, I'm enjoying it.